# Check if any character in a string is not in another string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, iterator, any

I have a function where the user inputs the string `s`.
If any character in `s` is not in `"0123456789e+-. "`, the function should return `False`.

I tried this:

```
if any(s) not in "0123456789e+-. ":
    return False
```

This:

```
if any(s not in "0123456789e+-. "):
    return False
```

And This:

```
if any(character for character in s not in "0123456789e+-. "):
    return False
```

How should I use the `any()` function in this case?

Comment: `if any(character not in "0123456789e+-. " for character in s ):`

Answer (score 3):

You want to iterate over every character in `s` and check if it is not in  the set `"0123456789e+-. "`

```
chars = set("0123456789e+-. ")
if any(c not in chars for c in s):
    return False
```

You can also use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) in this case to check for the same condition

```
chars = set("0123456789e+-. ")
if not all(c in chars for c in s):
    return False
```

Comment: How about just: `return all(c in set("0123456789e+-. ") for c in s)` ?

Comment: That's a good point @Austin but I didn't know if the OP wants to return `True` in the other case, hence I didn't add it

Comment: This will create a new set with every iteration, no? Not a big deal, but just one of those things.

Comment: Fair point @MadPhysicist updated accordingly!

Answer (score 3):

Just with `set`s difference:

```
pattern = "0123456789e+-. "
user_input = '=-a'

if set(user_input) - set(pattern):
    return False
```

---

or just test for negative subset:

```
if not set(user_input) < set(pattern):
    return False
```

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset